# Help identifying compact, flat connector found on brushless DC motor

Tags: connector, identification

Do you know the manufacturer or model number of the connector shown in this picture?  It came on an unidentified brushless DC motor.  Contacts shown are receptacles, not pins.  The contact pitch is 0.050 inch / 1.27 mm.

[image: flat mystery connector]

[image: flat mystery connector]

Answer (score 1):

I finally asked the right high reliability supplier.  The connector was a custom from MinECon .  The link below points to similar connectors.  Hope this updated answer helps the one other person on Earth who is looking for this type of connector.

http://www.min-e-con.com/s_series.html

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an unusual custom connector.  The wires are potted into the housing.  There is a special polarization pin on one side.

Having said that, this connector might still be able to mate with standard 0.050" [1.27 mm] male headers.